# recursive word tree insertion fails -reading object properties is failing

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, insertion

okay, so I am making a wordTree. just like any tree but with 28 branches " " , and "-", are included.

I have it set so the node as a prop called word, which is the string path to get to that node. and def, which is either null or a definition.

```
class wordNode{
    constructor(wordString,def){
        this.word = wordString;
        this.def= def;
        this.A=null;
        this.B=null;
        this.C=null;
        this.D=null;
        this.E=null;
        this.F=null;
        this.G=null;
        this.H=null;
        this.I=null;
        this.J=null;
        this.K=null;
        this.L=null;
        this.M=null;
        this.N=null;
        this.O=null;
        this.P=null;
        this.Q=null;
        this.R=null;
        this.S=null;
        this.T=null;
        this.U=null;
        this.V=null;
        this.W=null;
        this.X=null;
        this.Y=null;
        this.Z=null;
        this["-"]=null;
        this[" "]=null;
    }
}
```

is what the wordNode looks like... pretty simple...

the insertion however is failing in ways I don't understand.
words are getting transformed.

original     => unwanted change

EQUIVALUE   = >ELUIVALUE

GREASINESS  = >GRUASINESS

SPERMATOOEN = >SAIRMATOOEN

?

```
class WORDTREE{
 constructor(dictionaryArray){
        this.root = new wordNode("",null);
        dictionaryArray.forEach(entry=>{
            console.log(entry.word,"WORD");
            this.insert(entry);
        });
    }
    insert(wordObject){
        const wordStringArray = wordObject.word.split("");
        const targetLetter = wordStringArray[0];
        this.__insert(targetLetter, wordStringArray, this.root, wordObject,"");
    }
    __insert(letter,array, ref, word){
        const wordString =array.join("");
        const nextArray = wordString.split("");
        const nextLetter = array[0];
        nextArray.shift();
        if(ref[letter]==null){
            console.log(ref.word+nextLetter, ref.word, nextLetter, "a = b+c here?");
            ref[letter]=new wordNode(ref.word+nextLetter, (ref.word+nextLetter)==word.word?word.def:null);
        }
        const nextRef = ref[letter];
        if(nextArray.length>0){
            this.__insert(nextLetter,nextArray,nextRef,word);
        }
        else{
            console.log(nextRef.word);
            console.log("inserted at?");
            console.log(nextRef);
        }
        
    }
}
```

the dictionaryArrayObject i'm generated this from is structured like

```
[{word:"",def:""},{...}...]
```

I think `ref[letter] = new wordNode()` is failing under a specific condition?

Comment: ...derp... the class WORDTREE. adding that in

Comment: Let me guess: there's a word that starts with `ELU...`  preceding that `EQUIVALUE` word in your array?

Comment: will check, but it's not an ordered array. so it's possible...

Comment: It's not about ordered array. Your function mishandles the attachment of a word to that root node - if there's a word that already starts from the same first letter, its chain is used instead.

Comment: did we have to guess the structure of the input data of your WORDTREE object ?  Your explanations are very muddled, to believe that you want to lose us. pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the input structure is explained . [{word"",def:""},{...}...] @MisterJojo

Comment: @raina77ow, hmmm, I'm having trouble spotting what you mean. can you clarify any?

Comment: @raina77ow after a few tests, this appears to be an explanation... however I do not fully understand what is happening... still thinking though this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you wouldn't be better off with a simpler data structure.  We could have the same basic trie stucture including only the letters actually used, with a special value at leaf nodes to hold definitions.  Something like this:

```js
const dict = [
  {word: 'foo', def: 'foo def'},
  {word: 'fob', def: 'fob def'},
  {word: 'foolish', def: 'foolish def'},
  {word: 'bard', def: 'bard def'},
  {word: 'barstool', def: 'barstool def'},
  {word: 'bar', def: 'bar def'}
]

const tree = wordTree (dict)

//=> 
// {
//     b: {a: {r: {
//         $: 'bar def',
//         d: {$: 'bard def'},
//         s: {t: {o: {o: {l: {$: 'barstool def'}}}}}
//     }}},
//     f: {o: {
//             b: {$: 'fob def'},
//             o: {
//                 $: 'foo def',
//                 l: {i: {s: {h: {$: 'foolish def'}}}
//             }
//     }}
// }
```

We could build this with fairly standard recursive techniques, using plain objects for our data, with keys of the relevant letters, and the key `'$'` representing the definition.

The following are pure functions to create a tree from a array of `{word, def}` elements (`wordTree`), to create a new tree by inserting a word into an existing tree (`insertWord`), to list all the words in the tree (`listWords`), or to fetch the definition for a word in the list, returning `undefined` if it's not included (`getWord`).

```js
const wordTree = (words) => 
  words .reduce (insertWord, {}) 

const insertWord = (tree, {def, word: [letter, ...letters]}) => 
  letter
    ? {...tree, [letter]: insertWord (tree [letter] || {}, {def, word: letters})}
    : {...tree, $: def}

const listWords = (tree, prefix = '', {$, ...children} = tree) =>
  [
    ... ($ ? [prefix] : []), 
    ... Object .keys (children) .sort () .flatMap (c => listWords (tree [c], prefix + c))
  ]

const getWord = (tree, [letter, ...letters]) =>
  letter
    ? letter in tree && getWord (tree [letter], letters)
  : '$' in tree 
    ? tree ['$'] 
  : undefined

const dict = [
  {word: 'foo', def: 'foo def'},
  {word: 'fob', def: 'fob def'},
  {word: 'foolish', def: 'foolish def'},
  {word: 'bard', def: 'bard def'},
  {word: 'barstool', def: 'barstool def'},
  {word: 'bar', def: 'bar def'}
]

const tree = wordTree (dict)
console .log (getWord (tree, 'barstool'))
console .log (listWords (tree))
console .log (tree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If we wanted a `deleteWord` function as well, a simple naive version might be enough, using a helper that clones an object removing a particular key:

```js
const omitKey = (key, obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .filter (([k, v]) => k !== key))

const deleteWord = (tree, [letter, ...letters]) =>
  letter
    ? letter in tree ? {...tree, [letter]: deleteWord (tree [letter], letters)} : tree
    : omitKey ('$', tree)
```

This will leave behind some detritus.  It's probably not harmful, but if for instance, we deleted `'foolish'` from the list above, the resulting structure would include `l: {i: {s: {h: {}}}`, which is now unnecessary:

```js
// ...
    f: {o: {
            b: {$: 'fob def'},
            o: {
                $: 'foo def',
                l: {i: {s: {h: {}}}
            }
    }}
// ...
```

It's not harmful, as far as I can tell, but it feels less than clean.  This, on the other hand, cleans everything up really nicely, but at a likely significant performance cost:

```js
const deleteWord = (tree, targetWord) =>
  wordTree (
    listWords (tree)
      .filter (word => word !== targetWord)
      .map (word => ({word, def: getWord (tree, word)}))
  )
```

I'm sure that with a little thought, we could write something more elegant.

---

In any case, this is just a suggested alternative.  I find it quite a bit simpler than your constructor-based, pre-allocated version.  But, as always, YMMV.

### Update

That `delete` was bothering me.  I had to try to come up with something better.  I like this version:

```
const deleteWord = (tree, [letter, ...letters], child) => 
  letter 
    ? (child = deleteWord (tree [letter], letters)) && 
      Object .keys (child) .length == 0
        ? omitKey (letter, tree)
        : {...tree, [letter]: child}
    : omitKey ('$', tree)
```

I'm am perhaps a little to enamored of expression-only coding, and if that version is unclear because of the odd `&&` (which could also be done with a comma expression) and rewritten `child` parameter, then we could choose this equivalent instead:

```js
const deleteWord = (tree, [letter, ...letters]) => {
  if (!letter) {
    return omitKey ('$', tree)
  }
  const child = deleteWord (tree [letter], letters)
  return Object .keys (child) .length == 0
    ? omitKey (letter, tree)
    : {...tree, [letter]: child}
}
```

Either way, this has the right characteristics to me.  It cleans up behind itself and doesn't blow away the entire tree in order to do its work.

And while I'm here, I'm happy enough with the `wordTree` factory function.  It's elegant and reasonably performant, but I just want to note an alternative that is more in keeping with the rest of the code:

```js
const wordTree = ([word, ...words], tree = {}) =>
  word
    ? wordTree (words, insertWord (tree, word))
    : tree
```

I wouldn't actually recommend this.  Unless and until tail-call optimization becomes the norm, this will run quickly into recursion-depth problems.  But it's nice to see it alongside the rest of the recursive code.

Comment: this is nifty: I had ideas about attaching the methods to the tree itself instead of using a more functional approach. and this is mostly an experiment and learning for me. my goals currently, an exploratory gui with the canvas, and spellchecking/word prediction. I have other... weirder ideas (that likely won't pan out). I am going to have to reread this post a few times for it to really click

Comment: also, while a delete is useful, I suspect its use would be exceptionally rare.
nor would it require clean up in most cases, since this models a dictionary - there are often several other ways the parent node still go to form valid entries. removing the entry for bat would merely erase the definition, not the wordnode itself due to words like bash or banana... or battalion. and removing a node would be unusual for any use case I can think of.

Comment: @altruios: Right.  For the most part, a `delete` that left behind unnecessary but harmless stuff wouldn't be a major concern.  But for my own benefit, I may come back to this to find a clean version that does this without resorting to the big guns in my second implementation.

Comment: I mean to say, that the first would rarely result in a need for cleanup at all, considering the English language is about 171,000 words or so, which can be sorted compactly in a tree. most delete operations would just be removing the definition, but the leaf space could be much bigger than I am thinking... 5 letter words are about average so that leaf space is at most 308915776 spots... with 11881376 parents... that's assuming a perfect distribution of 1,2,3,4 letter words... so I don't know. thus my quest to be able to visualize this thing.

Comment: @altruios: I agree that the remainders after a delete would not be hugely important. Still, when deleting words like 'hypernationalistic' or 'postpsychoanalytic' from an English dictionary, we would leave behind emptry trees thirteen levels deep.  And 'polyphiloprogenitive' would leave one fourteen deep.  It's probably not a problem, but it's messy.

Comment: aye, agreed, in those cases. but removing a 4 letter word - would result in no nodes being removed (likely) - because it would still be needed for a 5 letter word. I'll try and find out that ratio:(removing a word results in empty children/removing a word results in no change to the structure).

Comment: @altruios: Added a cleaner `deleteWord` function.  It was an itch I simply had to scratch.

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of testing, @raina77ow was correct, the reference was not being handled correctly in the case of it being the root.
below are the corrected insert functions.

```
   insert(word){
       const wordArray = word.word.split("").map(x=>x.toUpperCase());
       
        this.__insert(word,wordArray,this.root);
   }
   __insert(wordObject,charArray,refNode){
       if(charArray.length>0){
            const nextRef = refNode[charArray[0]]|| new WordNode(refNode.word+charArray[0], null);
            !refNode[charArray[0]]?refNode[charArray[0]]=nextRef:null;
            charArray.shift();
            this.__insert(wordObject,charArray,nextRef);
        }
        else
            {
            refNode.__setDef(wordObject.definition);
        }  
   }
```